# I'm having trouble calling the vectors in an array rather than the whole array as a single vector

Tags: r

I'm creating an array which contains ten-thousand vectors, where each vector has 4 character vectors, which can be either "win" or "lose".

I then want to call each individual vector and use the "any" function to returns TRUE if any one character vector in each vector is "win", and false otherwise. AKA if the vector is c("lose", "lose", "lose", "lose"), it returns FALSE, and otherwise, TRUE.

I of course wish to do this all at once, and I thought it could be done either by passing the array of vectors through the "any" function and get an array back, like some other function allow, or by using the "apply" function with the array and "any() == TRUE" s arguments.

```
B <- 10000

set.seed(1)

a <- replicate(B, sample(c("lose","win"), 4, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.6, 0.4)))
```

## Option 1

```
celtic_wins <- any(a[,1:10000] == "win")
```

OR

## Option 2

```
celtic_wins <- apply(a, any() == "win")
```

What actually happens in both cases (I think but can't be sure) is that the array gets parsed into a vector of vectors, which r then treats as a single 40,000 element long vector, checks whether a single "win" character vector exists in the whole lot (which is like 99.99999999....% the case), and thus, returns a single TRUE statement, rather than 10,000 Boolean values.

If this is the case, I don't know how to create a work around; please help?

Comment: Use `apply`, but specify a margin! Work on a small example to understand what is happening!

Comment: Given that it is randomized, and the output would be 10,000 TRUE or FALSE statements long, I don't think I can.

Comment: Which is why you use a small example. If you set `B` to 5, figure out what works, you can *then* set `B` to  10000 and have confidence it is working.

Answer (score 1):

does this give you what you want?

```
apply(a,MARGIN = 2, FUN = function(x) {any(x=="win")})
```

as @Gregor mentioned below, this can be simplified to:

```
apply(a == "win", MARGIN = 2, any)
```

The first version may help you understand the `apply()` function better and what the arguments are doing, but once you understand what `apply()` is doing I would use the second version (@Gregor's version) in production as it is simpler and cleaner.

Comment: I'd recommend simplifying to `apply(a == "win", MARGIN = 2, any)`.

Comment: It does, though now I have to ask; you specified a function FUN inside the argument for the apply function. I'm assuming it works because the function is being defined AND called in the same place at the same time. If so, it seems like a neat trick, and I wonder if such a trick is commonly used and whether I should get into the the habit of using it myself.

Comment: @Gregor might be able to answer more intelligently than I can, but my example uses what is called a [lambda function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function). This is done because `any()` expects logical arguments, so in my `apply` call I take your matrix as it is (character) and convert it to a logical vector within my `FUN` argument. @Gregor instead passed `a=="win"` to the `X` argument of `apply()`, which converts your character matrix into a logical matrix before applying `FUN`. He then passes the `any()` function to `FUN` where it is applied to the matrix (which is now logical).

Answer (score 1):

You can see if `'win'` is part of a column `x` by checking whether the sum of `x == 'win'` is positive. `a == 'win'` will give a matrix with the same dimensions as `a`, with elements equal to `TRUE` if the corresponding element of `a` is `'win'`, and `FALSE` otherwise. `colSums(a == 'win')` creates a vector whose i-th element is the sum of column i in the matrix `a == 'win'`.

```
colSums(a == 'win') > 0
```